# 'System.UriFormatException' while using InAppBrowser Plugin in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, inappbrowser

I am trying to open an URL which will initiate a download of file from server in Windows Phone 7 PhoneGap app.

I have enabled InAppBrowser plugin in config.xml as follows  and also added the relevant code in the server side like (I want the URL to be opened in system browser)

var ref = window.open('http://www.xyz.com/download.aspx', '_system');

But when I tried to open this it throws the following exception (from output window)

A first chance exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll

Error:"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-role='footer']#sfdmfdOptionsNavbar li a# file:http://www.xyz.com/js/jquery/SmartphoneJquery/jquery-2.0.0.js Line:1612"

The thread '' (0xfc108e2) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

ERROR: Exception in ProcessCommand :: TargetInvocationException

ERROR: failed to InvokeMethodNamed :: open on Object :: InAppBrowser

The thread '' (0xaa5031a) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
AppClosing

Note: I have changed the original ip to xyz.com for illustration purpose. The original ip is valid and working fine locally in my environment.

Following is the log from the call stack

> System.dll!System.Uri.CreateThis(string uri, bool dontEscape, System.UriKind uriKind) + 0xc4 bytes
>       System.dll!System.Uri.Uri(string uriString, System.UriKind uriKind) + 0x1d bytes
>       WPCordovaClassLib.dll!WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands.InAppBrowser.ShowSystemBrowser(string url) + 0xe bytes 
>       WPCordovaClassLib.dll!WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands.InAppBrowser.open(string options) + 0x53 bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, bool isBinderDefault, System.Reflection.Assembly caller, bool verifyAccess, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0x168 bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(object obj, object[] parameters) + 0xa bytes
>       WPCordovaClassLib.dll!WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands.BaseCommand.InvokeMethodNamed(string methodName, object[] args) + 0x13 bytes
>       WPCordovaClassLib.dll!WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.NativeExecution.ProcessCommand.AnonymousMethod__2(object func) + 0x31 bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStartHelper(System.Threading.ThreadHelper t) + 0x34 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0xb bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x63 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStartHelper() + 0x2a bytes

Please let me know what is going wrong.

Note: The same URL works fine in a Windows Phone 7 IE browser.

Comment: Could you provide us the details of the exception? The cause of the error is probably mentioned in there (the `Message` property of the exception, and the inner exception if any)

Comment: @KooKiz thanks for looking into this. I have modified my original post to include the additional information about the error from the output window.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **encodeURI()** method with your URL. I think it will resolve your problem

```
var ref = window.open(encodeURI('http://www.xyz.com/download.aspx'), '_system');
```